# Face blemish concealment

Tags: personal-care

What is the absolute best way to conceal face blemishes. I have tried everything I can think of and need to look well in a picture coming up soon.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Welcome to Lifehackers. Is your picture a portrait or a group photo?

Answer (score 3):

There are different techniques to consider when sitting for a photographic portrait with a skin blemish.

- If you know (or you can contact) the photographer, ask for a reference to a make-up technician who can apply photographically compatible materials just before the session. You could either go to their studio or ask that the technician come to your shoot. Make up is used by every professional (actors, politicians, business executives, etc.) before being photographed. It's standard procedure.
- A well-stocked pharmacy or department store with a cosmetics department typically has many different specially formulated "solutions" made to cover skin blemishes temporarily. You might want to get hypo-allergenic materials to avoid damaging your sensitive skin further.
- Do nothing special to yourself but speak to the photographer who can use software after the image has been taken to modify (retouch) your likeness without affecting your features. This is done ALL the time and can be trivial (loose strand of hair removed) to a complete make-over. You may know the practice called 'shopping' named after a popular software called 'Photoshop.' This is also done in addition to using make-up for skin treatment.

You look marvellous!

Good Luck. Have a good shoot!

Comment: Especially the latter. A good professional photographer will have to touch the shots anyway (post processing the .raw images for printing/publishing), while many will do *some* beautifying, it won’t hurt to nicely ask them to remove the blemishes.